# Seismic data processing software

Tags: geophysics, seismology, software

For processing seismic data, why is [Seismic Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_Unix) so important? What distinguishes it from other seismic processing software like [GLOBE Claritas](http://www.globeclaritas.com/) or [Omega](http://www.software.slb.com/products/omega)?

Is it argued that processing capabilities are superior to other seismic processing software or that it is easier to use? Does it get recommended for use because of cost or its wide use?

Comment: I think this question is about opinions. Maybe try rephrasing it to something that has a specific answer.

Comment: It would be useful if you could edit your question to either make it clear how exactly you're measuring "importance", or remove this aspect entirely (and make it a question purely about the main differences between the three packages). I agree with Antonio that, as it stands, this question seems to invite heavily opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages as [Seismic Unix](http://www.cwp.mines.edu/cwpcodes/) and [Madagascar](http://www.ahay.org/wiki/Main_Page) represent a different philosophy than commercial products.

The packages are open source, so any user can look at the [code](https://github.com/JohnWStockwellJr/SeisUnix), understand how it works (or why it doesn't) and even produce reproducible research so other geophysicists can test the results and use the methods. A great way to learn about seismic processing is indeed by reproduce earlier [studies](http://www.ahay.org/wiki/Reproducible_Documents).

A lot of new processing methods are developed within the Seismic Unix and Madagascar groups, and they are great sources if one needs a special tool for a special problem.

The packages are free and are widely used by universities, but they can also be useful for processing companies. It is easy to share or sell projects if they are built in code that everyone have access too.

If the processing capabilities are superior or not is generally about opinion, but at least the results can compare well with commercial packages. Sometimes they can be used in the same workflow, e.g. the geometry might be easier to do with a GUI but processing might be just as easy in a script.

My own experience is that the learning curve is rather steep in the beginning, but once you understand the basic tools, Seismic Unix and Madagascar are just as easy, or even easier to work with. Especially if there is a problem or you need to do something unconventional with the data.

Comment: Thank you Tbb I'm new in using seismic unix and now i face problem with how to set up geometry for seismic data using sushw order the geometry was in three files that are bad formated. What do you how solve this problem???

Comment: Hard to say in a short comment. If you are using synthetic data or not have any header data, sushw can be useful. Usually I prepare the geometry outside SU. SQL is useful, or just spreadsheet. It's easier to build a sps file of you can see what you are doing. The mailing list for SU is rather good if you can provide an example. If your question is of more general character and can be useful for others, I don't see any problems of posting it at SE.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is the sushw defined the geometry trace by trace i have headers but not updated. So I try to update the headers which gx,gy,sx,sy from sps file. The coordinates sorted in a way just as new ones that have new coordinates. It should be sorted corresponding to traces sorting is it possible.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, but it sound as you want to perform binning. In the binning process, the traces are sorted according to the position in relation to the source to generate CMP-gathers.

Comment: I have another question. I used fourier transformation with seismic unix to transform from T-X domain to F-K domain to dip filter. How to transform from F-K to T-x domain??